# Solving $\operatorname{arccsc}(\sqrt{37})+\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{arcsin}\frac{3}{5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

My question is

> $$\operatorname{arccsc}(\sqrt{37})+\operatorname{arcsin}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{arcsin}\frac{3}{5}$$
> Find value of $x$.

I have converted all the functions to arctan as it's suggested to solve such kind of problem by converting to arctan, then I tried using arctan formulae but couldn't get anywhere. Could anyone help me with how to start this problem, thanks

$$\operatorname{arctan} \frac{1}{6} + \operatorname{arctan}\frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{arcsin} \frac{3}{5}$$

Comment: Maybe you can edit the question to add the conversions to arctan?

Comment: Consider taking the sine of both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{6}+\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}=a$$

Where, $a=\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{3}{5}$

$\sin2a=\frac{3}{5}$, further $\cos2a=\frac{4}{5}$ (you can verify using a triangle)

Now, $$\cos2a=\frac{1-\tan^2a}{1+\tan^2a}=\frac{4}{5}$$

On solving, we get $\tan a=\frac{1}{3}$

Now,

$$\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{6}+\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}$$

Using $\tan^{-1}a-\tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)$

We get

> $$x=\frac{6}{19}$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\arctan \frac{1}{6} + \arctan\frac{x}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \arcsin \frac{3}{5}$$

take $\tan$ on both sides and use $\tan\frac\theta2=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$, we get

$$\frac{\frac16+\frac x2}{1-\frac16\cdot\frac x2}=\frac{1-\cos\left(\arcsin\frac{3}{5}\right)}{\frac35}=\frac13$$
hence

$$x=\frac6{19}$$

Comment: you are welcome @quasto